# Insert values into array of dictionary

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have an array of dictionary with two dictionaries in them like so..

```
[
{
    "sellingPrice" : "499",
    "id" : "5",
    "quantity" : "-2",
    "transaction_id" : "",
    "shipping_charges" : "",
    "payment_method" : "",
    "taxes" : "",
    "applied_coupon_code" : "",
    "discount_price" : "",
    "transaction_type" : "",
    "remaining_balance" : "",
    "grand_total" : ""
   },
   {
    "sellingPrice" : "500",
    "id" : "8",
    "quantity" : "79",
    "transaction_id" : "",
    "shipping_charges" : "",
    "payment_method" : "",
    "taxes" : "",
    "applied_coupon_code" : "",
    "discount_price" : "",
    "transaction_type" : "",
    "remaining_balance" : "",
    "grand_total" : ""

  }
]
```

Here, just the first 3 keys have values. Now if I want to add a value "COD" to the key `transaction_id` how can I achieve it..?

Also please note that the number of dictionaries in the array is not always 2. It can be any number. So when I give the value "COD" to the key `transaction_id` no matter what the number of dictionaries be, the change should be updated in all of them.

**EDIT** I tried something like this till now..

```
dictionary["transaction_id"] = "CASH"
arrayOfDictionary.append(dictionary)
```

But this adds one more dictionary with the value of `transaction_id` as "CASH" giving a total of 2 dictionaries instead of 2.

Comment: Iterate over the array, updating each dictionary. Be aware that arrays and dictionaries are value types in Swift, so be sure to update the dictionary in place.

Comment: @Bilal edited the code with what has been tried so far...

Comment: @Paulw11 maybe couldn't get it all. Could you mind suggesting an answer..?

Comment: Is there a particular reason not to use a custom struct or class?

Comment: No @vadian.Nothing in specific..

Comment: Then do it and use a custom data model. It makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the array and change the `transaction_id` for each dict.

```
arrayOfDictionary.indices.forEach({ arrayOfDictionary[$0]["transaction_id"] = "COD" })
```

If you want to do multiple updates, you can simply do this inside the `forEach` loop. It will change or add the value respectively.

```
arrayOfDictionary.indices.forEach({
    arrayOfDictionary[$0]["transaction_id"] = "COD"
    arrayOfDictionary[$0]["anotherKey"] = "anotherValue"
})
```

Also, note that you have an array of closures and not an array of dictionaries. You have to change your curly braces `{ }` to square braces `[ ]`

```
var arrayOfDictionary = [
    [
        "sellingPrice" : "499",
        "id" : "5",
        "quantity" : "-2",
        "transaction_id" : "",
        "shipping_charges" : "",
        "payment_method" : "",
        "taxes" : "",
        "applied_coupon_code" : "",
        "discount_price" : "",
        "transaction_type" : "",
        "remaining_balance" : "",
        "grand_total" : ""
    ],
    [
        "sellingPrice" : "500",
        "id" : "8",
        "quantity" : "79",
        "transaction_id" : "",
        "shipping_charges" : "",
        "payment_method" : "",
        "taxes" : "",
        "applied_coupon_code" : "",
        "discount_price" : "",
        "transaction_type" : "",
        "remaining_balance" : "",
        "grand_total" : ""

    ]
]
```

Comment: .@Yannick So if I want to add different values to the other keys also which are now empty, should I always do this.. `arrayOfDictionary.indices.forEach({ arrayOfDictionary[$0]["transaction_id"] = "COD" })
`

Comment: ..depending on what my key & value is...?

Comment: I would go with this option. If you want to update multiple values, you can simply do this inside the `forEach` loop.

Comment: Ok @Yannick, maybe I got a bit stuck on what u said regarding updating multiple values. You mean I can mention those multiple values in one foreach separated by comma..?

Answer (score 0):

*For the purpose of simplifying the answer, I assumed that there is only one key in the dictionaries.*

You could achieve it by *mapping* your current array, like this:

```
var myArray = [["transaction_id": ""], ["transaction_id": ""]]

myArray = myArray.map { (dict: [String: String]) -> [String: String] in
    var copyDict = dict
    copyDict["transaction_id"] = "COD"

    return copyDict
}

print(myArray)
// [["transaction_id": "COD"], ["transaction_id": "COD"]]
```